# return pixel colors in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, pixel

I am trying to analyze the pixel colors of an image with extension '.png' in MATLAB. I want to return the amount of pixels that are colored within a certain range of a certain RGB value.

I am trying to use the ['imread' function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html) to analyze the image. It returns an array of values 0-255. How do I sort these values to return an amount of pixels close to a certain numerically defined color?

Comment: Something like [imhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a specified tolerance `tol`, you can determine how many colours are within a certain range by splitting up the image into its three channels and checking if each colour in each channel is within the range.  Using [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) to check the total number of non-zero pixels is something to consider here.  You can create `logical` matrices that check if each channel is within a certain tolerance for each colour, then logical ANDing them all together and checking for the number of non-zero entries that results after this computation:

Something like this, given that your image is stored in `im`:

```
R = 100;
G = 128;
B = 123; %// Example
tol = 5; %// +/- 5 pixels
imd = double(im); %// For precision
num = nnz(abs(imd(:,:,1)-R) < tol & ...
          abs(imd(:,:,2)-G) < tol & ...
          abs(imd(:,:,3)-B) < tol);
```